# Button Clicks Counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jQuery code that count my button clicks, but for some reason it stops after only one click. Please help me fix it.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $(this).val(this.textContent + 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.value` to get the current value:

```
$(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()) + 1);
  });
});
```

Snippet:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()) + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="0">
```

Comment: Preference to this answer because it doesn't allow js to infer the type of the value of the button, and instead parses it to an integer first.

Comment: Thanks @RickCalder.

Answer (score 0):

Inputs generally do not have meaningful `textContent`s - rather, they have *values*. To retrieve the current *value* from the button, either call `.val()` on a jQuery collection with that element, or access the plain element's `.value`.

Note that because `.value`s are always *strings*, you'll also have to cast it to a number in order to add 1 to it properly, otherwise you'll concatenate:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).val(Number($(this).val()) + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="0">
```